# sort object in google maps v3 sidebar

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a sidebar that works here but is not alphabetized: www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/
I've tried to alphabetize here: www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/index_sort.php, but now the sidebar text links aren't linking to the correct map.  I understand why this is (have reordered the array, and it doesn't know how to connect to the original "batch" array), but I don't know how to order the list on the sidebar yet keep the connection between the links and the map.  I know I could simply order the spreadsheet which is converted into the xml document alphabetically, but I need it to remain in the order that it is...which isn't alphabetically.  So I need to do this ordering within the script it seems.  Any suggestions?  It would seem that I could order the way I display the names on the sidebar without changing the "myclick(i)" number that matches the "batch" marker objects.  I can clarify further if needed.  Thanks for any help,
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pay attention to the order you do things in.  You can either sort the array, keeping a copy of the original, and referencing the markers there by there original index:

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/wrh_noaa_gov_rec_v2_sort_0.html)

Or you can sort the array (changing all the indices), then recreate the sidebar to match:

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/wrh_noaa_gov_rec_v2_sort.html)

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks again.  Can you clarify how the function is working?  I understand what it's doint but I'm familiar with all the syntax. a.myname < b.myname ? -1 : 1  It seems like you create two identicaly arrays to start with...is that how it maintains the correct indexing for the markers?  Thanks again.

Comment: I did it two different ways.  The first time with 2 arrays, one sorted but using a reference to the original array, the second example sorts all the entries and regenerates the indexes to the markers (as I tried to indicate in my answer).  If you didn't get that out of my answer, help me clarify it.